# Does OCI (Oracle Call Interface) use COM (Component Object Model)?

Tags: oracle, com, oracle-call-interface

Does Oracle's OCI library actually use COM to interact with the Oracle database?

We have a COM DLL that calls Oracle through OCI, and one of our customers is reporting the error message

```
ORA-24550: signal received: Unhandled exception: Code=e0434f4d Flags=1
```

Since the DLL does not use COM to call Oracle, but uses the OCI library to call Oracle, I can only conclude that one of the following is happening:

1. The OCI library actually uses COM "under the hood" to get to the Oracle database.
2. There is some sort of COM or .NET "add-on" that Oracle is calling, but I don't know anything about it.

I am hoping that it is #2, or at least isn't #1. If Oracle is not being called through COM, then it should not be returning an error with code e0434f4d (where 43, 4f, 4d are ASCII for C, O, M).

Comment: What makes you think that the error message indicates OCI is using COM? Unhandled exceptions can occur outside of COM as well. (And I'm pretty sure OCI is **not** using COM)

Comment: Since the Code=e0434f4d looks like an HRESULT, I would assume that COM is involved. And it appears, from a Google search that I did, that e0434f4d isn't specific to Oracle. I am just trying to confirm that this is an error in Oracle and not in my COM object and not in the .NET code that calls the COM object.

Comment: I'm with @a_horse_with_no_name - AFAIK OCI isn't a COM object. The references I found to e0434f4d indicated it's a CLR exception, which I believe means .Net is involved somehow/where, and I don't believe OCI has anything to do with .Net. You might look at [MANAGED DEBUGGING with WinDbg](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/08/24/managed-debugging-with-windbg-breaking-on-an-exception-part-1.aspx) or [Crash Dump Analysis Patterns](http://www.dumpanalysis.org/blog/index.php/2007/07/20/crash-dump-analysis-patterns-part-17/) for ideas. Good luck.